# How to use a functional in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe and want to do different things with it. Now my function has this structure:

```
def process_dataframe(df, save_to_file, print_to_screen, etc):
    ...
    if save_to_file:
        df.to_csv(filename)
    elif print_to_screen:
        print df
    elif...
```

Which is an ugly if else case. I want to use a functional instead. A function pointer. Something like this. I create several functions:

```
def save_to_file(df, filename):
    return create_function(to_csv, filename???)
def print_to_screen(df):
    return create_function(print)
```

Which means I can change the structure of my function to this single line instead:

```
result = process_dataframe(save_to_file)
...
...
def process_dataframe(df, my_functional):
    return my_functional(df)
```

The problem is that I dont understand the syntax. For instance, how to return the class member function ".to_csv" in "save_to_file()"? How does "save_to_file()" look like? Which args does it take?

Of course, I could use a lambda instead of defining each function. But I want to understand how to define functions first. The next step with lambdas, I can figure out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make sure this is actually what you want to do, but assuming it is, you can just write a function that calls functions (and passes through arguments), like this:

```
def process_df(df, function, *args, **kwargs):
    function(df, *args, **kwargs)
```

And define your two actions.

```
def print_to_screen(df):
    print df

def save_to_file(df, filename):
    df.to_csv(filename)
```

Then you can use these as you like:

```
In [193]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,4,5]], columns=['a','b','c'])

In [197]: process_df(df, print_to_screen)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  5

In [198]: process_df(df, save_to_file, 'temp.csv')
#writes temp.csv
```

Comment: Thanx. Just what I wanted. A follow-up question; is there are neater way to do this? (Want to get rid of the huge if-else clause)

Comment: It's not clear why you want everything in one function like this or what that gets you.  The functions 'belong' to the DataFrame, so why not just use `df.to_csv`, etc?

Comment: I want to process the dataframe in different ways, in different places in my code. Sometimes I want to do A, other times B, C, D, etc. Instead of having a if else clause in every different places in my code, I insert just one line: "process_df(...)" now, thanks to your help. Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: I'm asking more fundamentally, why do you need a `process_df` function?  If at some point you want to write a CSV, use `df.to_csv`, if you want to print, use `print df`, etc.  What does wrapping it in a function get you?

Comment: I am doing analyses of data. Sometimes I want to save the data for inspection in Excel. Sometimes I want to illuminate another aspect of the data. From run to run, I examine different aspects all the time. I change aspect all the time. I do something with the data look at it this way, do another thing look at the data that way, etc. So I dont want a big if else clause with all the different possible examinations riddled all over my code. How would you have approached this problem where you need to call different functions all the time depending on what you think of at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I dont understand the syntax. For instance, how to
>   return the class member function ".to_csv" in "save_to_file()?"

I think what you are asking is this :

```
def save_to_file(filename):
    def df_to_csv(df):
        return df.to_csv(filename)
return df_to_csv
```

And the call:

```
foo = save_to_file('myfile.csv')
foo(df)  # <- here "df" will be saved to "myfile.csv"
```

You could also do this (which I believe is something you originally wanted):

```
def save_to_file(df, filename):
    def df_to_csv():
       return df.to_csv(filename)
return df_to_csv
```

And then call it like so:

```
foo = save_to_file(df, 'myfile.csv')
foo()  # <- "df" is saved to "myfile.csv"
```

But to me this seems not much less ugly than the first solution, so you might want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Rethink my approach? Sure. I basically want to use one single function call which will sometimes do "df.to_csv(filename)", and other times do "print df", etc etc. How would you suggest to solve this? Sometimes I want to use args, sometimes not. Sometimes I want to call member functions for "df". Other times just call ordinary functions. etc.

Comment: You didn't give enough details for me to come up with any "solution". My original solution might do for you (if you just want to pack everything in a function and then call it without any parameters if you choose to), but it just seems that this is something I would do differently.

Comment: Ok, and how would you do it differently?

Comment: I already told you, you need to provide more details on what you want, for me to be able to help you.

Comment: I want to apply one single function call on "df". Sometimes the function will call member functions of "df". Sometimes it will just print "df". I dont want a switch case. I am a Python newbie, so I dont really understand how my question is unclear. As I know so little, I tend to skip over crucial details. What are those crucial details you need to know?

Comment: How and when do you choose the function to call inside process_dataframe, do you choose it once and then call it depending on some condition? Or do you make many functions and call them inside some loop? Do you need the resulting function (ready to be called by process_dataframe) to have the same parameters all the time, or will you provide additional parameters inside process_dataframe depending on some other condition?